# Niyat for Sunnah Umrah Namaz

Tags: salat, sunnah, arabic, umrah

Assalaamualaikum

Please Share the Niyat for 2 Rakat Sunnah Umrah Namaz (prayer) in Arabic with transliteration and translation.

Answer (score 2):

```
            In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful
```

To be honest, I don’t know what its precise phrase is, but as far as I can remember, (according to Shia Islam) **it is not Wajib to recite the exact phrase of the Salah. Actually, it could be sufficient if you know what you are saying prayer for. I mean it is enough if you know about the kind of your prayer, and it is not Wajib to say the exact phrase …**

Since for example whenever you go to say prayer (e.g. Salah of  Fajr), accordingly you know what your intention is and in fact you know what you are doing and what you are praying for, the significant point is reciting the various parts of the prayer.

Actually, I reckon that as it is obvious from its name Niah, it is related to the intention, not reciting.
Anyhow, in accordance with the mentioned issue, I assume it is sufficient for you just to mention the phrase of “2 Rakat Sunnah Umrah Namaz”

(Hopefully my info. be profitable for you somewhat)